Can converting and handling an Excel file with MemoryStream infect a server?
I'm making an Excel handler to save Excel content in a database.
I'm using MemoryStream to read the files content and make the validations and inserts.
My question is, if the Excel file that is used is somehow infected by a virus, can it infect the server with this procedure? I'm not storing it anywhere in the server, just reading it with MemoryStream and then handling it with XSSFWorkbook.
I want to know if I still would have to check the file for virus before handling it this way. I think not, because it's not being "written" in the server this way, I'm just reading it IRT, and copying to MemoryStream.

Hahahaha. This is exactly why nobody listens to you. This is why Stackoverflow is getting out of the business... and I'm glad.
